# Android onNewIntent always receives same Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

I have 2 `Notifications`: one for incoming messages, one for outgoing messages. On `Notification` click, it sends the `PendingIntent` to self. I put in an extra value to determine which of the `Notifications` was clicked:

```
private static final int INID = 2;
private static final int OUTID = 1;

private void update(boolean incoming, String title, String message, int number) {
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Entry.class);
    intent.putExtra((incoming ? "IN" : "OUT"), incoming);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(Entry.this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    Notification noti = new Notification(incoming ? R.drawable.next : R.drawable.prev, incoming ? "Incoming message" : "Outgoing message", System.currentTimeMillis());
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
    noti.setLatestEventInfo(this, title, message, pi);
    noti.number = number;
    notificationManager.notify(incoming ? INID : OUTID, noti); 
}
```

And capture the `Intent` in the `onNewIntent` method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) 
        for (String id : new ArrayList<String>(intent.getExtras().keySet())) {
            Object v = intent.getExtras().get(id);
            System.out.println(id + ": " + v);
        }
    else
        log("onNewIntent has no EXTRAS");
}
```

plus the `manifest` line that makes sure that there's only one task (in `activity` tag):

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

I logged that it runs through the `onNewIntent` method, but always use the same `intent` (IE if I click either the IN or OUT `notification`, the intent extra always contains the same `bundle`(logs: `OUT: false`)). It's always the Intent that was created last, which I found out because the initialization of both intents happens in another sequence than when they are changed:

```
private void buttonClick(View v) {      
    update(true, "IN", "in", 1);
    update(false, "OUT", "out", 3);
}

private void setNotificationSettings() {
    update(false, "IN", "===out message===", 0);
    update(true, "OUT", "===in message===", 0);
}
```

**Why do I always receive the same (last created) `Intent`?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are passing same `requestcode` for all intent that why you reciev last intent everytime, so you have to pass different `requestcode` in pending intent..

like as below code

**Your code:**

```
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(Entry.this, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

**Need to change:**

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(Entry.this, your_request_code, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: How do I define my request code? Or should I make a 2 request codes, one for each notification? Or should they just be equal to their `notification id`? I have this code now in the line you said: `incoming ? 678452056 : 678452099` and that seems to work, thanks by the way.

Comment: `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` does not belong here